# Slicing a huge image to parts with dimensions of more than 1000 pixels

Tags: gimp, image-editing

I have 1,000 x 15,000 pixel image (that is, a super tall scroll), and I would like to split the image in parts with dimensions of 1,000 x 2,000 pixels (the scroll cut up vertically in 8 pieces).

I tried to use the slice tool in Photoshop, like in the image below, and 'Divide Horizontally Into' 2000 pixel slices, but Photoshop (CS6 64 bit) won't go over 1,000px.

[image: Slicing dialog in Photoshop]

Something I thought of was slicing to 1,000px pieces and adding them together again with a batch job, but maybe there is some tool available which can slice 2000px parts?

Comment: For the second question, I assume the Save for Web feature has a height limit of 8192 pixel, and won't let you save anything bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Download [GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/)
2. In path\to\installation\GIMP 2\share\gimp\2.0\scripts, put this script: [New Guides Every X Pixels](http://registry.gimp.org/node/13774).
3. Using this script, we'll place a guide every 2000 pixels: Image > Guides > New Guides Every X Pixels. Put in horizontal guides and 2000 pixels.
4. Use [Guillotine](http://docs.gimp.org/en/plug-in-guillotine.html) (Image > Transform > Guillotine) or [Slice](http://docs.gimp.org/en/python-fu-slice.html) (Filters > Web > Slice) to slice the image.
5. That was easy.

Answer (score 0):

I have been having a hard time with this too, and I'm pretty sure I've figured it out. For whatever reason, Photoshop is having trouble because the file is so TALL. Try saving the file into two vertical sections, so that each is 50% of the original file height. When you try to save a slice for web now, it should default to 100%.